# restoring grub (was dual-boot, now single-boot to Ubuntu)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a dual-boot system which, until very recently, brought up a grub menu whose default OS was Ubuntu (in addition to Windows 10 and memory test options).

Something happened.  Now, **the computer boots straight into Ubuntu, seemingly without ever going through grub**.  The file */boot/grub/grub.cfg* still exists and is not obviously damaged.

I think I'm supposed to have an SSD.  However, the output of *lsblk* appears to contradict this:

```
$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,TYPE,ROTA | grep -v " loop "
NAME   FSTYPE     SIZE MOUNTPOINT                     TYPE ROTA
sda             931.5G                                disk    1
├─sda1 ntfs       350M                                part    1
├─sda2 ntfs     619.5G                                part    1
├─sda3 ntfs       524M                                part    1
├─sda4              1K                                part    1
├─sda5 ext4     303.2G /                              part    1
└─sda6 swap         8G [SWAP]                         part    1
sr0              1024M                                rom     1
$
```

I wonder if the SSD died and took out some critical component of the boot loader?  (But I'm only speculating: maybe I never had an SSD, or *lsblk* isn't telling me what I think it's telling me ...)

It's not a tragedy to be without Windows 10 for a week or so :)  But I would like to have the option restored to boot into either OS.  So, help please: **how can I restore grub without risking my ability to boot into Ubuntu?**  Thank you.

Comment: If it is booting, you have grub working. If grub has only found one install, it boots directly without menu as you really only have the one choice. If UEFI, you can press escape right after UEFI screen. If BIOS, press & hold shift key right after BIOS screen. If Windows updates turned on Windows fast start up, and Ubuntu updated grub, it would not find Windows. If UEFI see if you can boot Windows directly from UEFI boot menu, often f12 or f10, same key you use to choose USB flash drive to boot with. Grub only boots/finds working Windows. or Windows that is not hibernated nor needs chkdsk.

Comment: @oldfred, I'm using BIOS not UEFI.  Can't test it now, as I have something running, but when I do get a few minutes to interrupt the boot sequence as you suggest then what am I looking for?

Comment: Do not run any fixes until someone had reviewed report. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: please attach the grub configuration.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EijfpE89

Comment: No response to paste, so deleting.  Thanks for the pointer to the boot-repair utility.